# How to compile vue3 SFC component .ce.vue into .js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, web-component, vite, vue-sfc

I am looking for a way to compile a **"single-file component"** (`.vue` or `.ce.vue` extension) with console tools into a js. the project is made with yii2. here is what i tried:

Following [this guide](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html#building-custom-elements-with-vue) i managed to define a custom element (without SFC .vue):

```js
import { defineCustomElement } from 'vue'

const MyVueElement = defineCustomElement({
  // normal Vue component options here
  props: {},
  emits: {},
  template: `...`,

  // defineCustomElement only: CSS to be injected into shadow root
  styles: [`/* inlined css */`]
})

// Register the custom element.
// After registration, all `<my-vue-element>` tags
// on the page will be upgraded.
customElements.define('my-vue-element', MyVueElement)
```

[this guide](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/tree/main/packages/plugin-vue#using-vue-sfcs-as-custom-elements) mentions "Using Vue SFC as Custom Elements", but i have no clue how to run it, as well as this [@vue/compiler-sfc](https://github.com/vuejs/core/tree/main/packages/compiler-sfc).

using the library built with [vitejs in library mode](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode) makes my (php) app throw

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

so what is the best way to build a SFC

**MyTest.ce.vue**

```js
<template>
    <div>
        hello world
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        tag:  'my-test',
        name: 'MyTest',
        data() {
            return { count: 0 }
        },
    };
</script>

<style scoped>
    div {
        font-size: 200%;
    }
</style>
```

into a `.js` that i can load in my app, preferably with a single command line tool, without webpack or similar?